# Possible problem of the rtw_8821ce wifi driver in 6.1 kernel

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, 22.04

I noticed that wifi speed in my laptop decreases after rebooting the router. When I bring the laptop close to the router the speed is restored. And it does not decrease when I bring the laptop back. I use 6.1 kernel, driver rtw_8821ce, Ubuntu 22.04. My phone works normally with wifi in both locations.

Comment: I have tried 5.15.0-97-generic kernel. No Wifi and Bluetooth at all. I have returned back to 6.1.0-1036-oem. Yes, 6.1 is oem kernel, but it is working.